# Determining correct context path behind AJP proxy

Tags: apache, jboss, wildfly, ajp

I've got a WildFly/JBoss with more than one web application. Each has its own context-root.

For example:

- *webapp1.war* is mapped with `<context-root>/webapp1\</context-root>`
- *webapp2.war* is mapped with `<context-root>/webapp2\</context-root>`
- ...

In an upstream Apache server we have an AJP configuration for each of the web applications:

```
<VirtualHost webapp1.example.com:80>
ProxyPass / ajp://123.123.123.123:8009/webapp1/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost webapp2.example.com:80>
ProxyPass / ajp://123.123.123.123:8009/webapp2/
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is, that *webapp1* and *webapp2* still think, they are visible under `/webapp.../` (as `HttpServletRequest.getContextPath()` still returns that path) and all generated absolute URLs (for example to CSS and JS files from the application) do include the context path.

How can I tell WildFly/JBoss to provide the context path without the (invisible) prefix when it is accessed by the AJP connection?

Comment: What version of WildFly/JBoss EAP are you using? I just tested on WildFly 27 and I do see the value defined in the `jboss-web.xml` returned.

Comment: Exactly that is the problem, that the value from `jboss-web.xml` _is_ returned. So our web application generates an URL of `/webapp1/...`, which is not available, because the ProxyPass rule will map it to `/webapp1/webapp1`. I thought, that maybe there is an AJP option or similar to use the _actual_ context path from the Apache.

Comment: Got it. I don't see a specific setting for that unless I overlooked it https://docs.wildfly.org/27/wildscribe/subsystem/undertow/server/ajp-listener/index.html. I wonder if use a rewrite filter would work though.

Comment: Do you mean `mod_rewrite`? Or a `<rewrite />` rule in standalone? Or a `javax.servlet.Filter`? The later would probably work, but it seems I would have to write one of my own (which depends on some request header to identify the AJP request), as I don't see any out of the box which rewrites `HttpServletRequest.getContextPath()`.